# Arrays in headers

Tags: c++, arrays, header

The following problem is a small part of my project. I have simplified the problem a lot.

I have declared both the array size and the array globally.

```
int N;
double array[N];
```

Now using a function I am filling the array.

```
void arrayfill()
{
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Next, I have a function which sums over the elements of all the array depending upon a variable var.

```
double sum(int var)
{
    double s;
    for(int i=0;i<var;i++)
    {
        s+=array[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

Now, what I want is to create a header file which will have the fill function, another header which will have the sum function and finally from the main function I want to call sum(). The reason I am doing this is because I want to fill the array once and keep using sum() at many different places with different values of var.

Can anybody help?

Comment: That `sum` function isn't going to work out too well due to `s` being uninitialized.  Also, why not just pass a pointer to the buffer and the size instead of using globals?  Also, why not use better techniques in general instead of using global variables?

Comment: You don't even need a `sum` function.  `std::accumulate` does this already, and it works with regular arrays.  Heck, even `std::fill` takes the place of `arrayfill`.  *I have simplified the problem a lot.*  -- `std::fill(array, array + N, 1); ... auto value = std::accumulate(array, array + var, 0.0);`  That makes things even more simple.

Comment: I wonder why so many people don't use compiler warnings to their advantage. The uninitialised local variable is not an accident; you have to actively lower your warning level and/or ignore warnings for this bug to make it into your executable.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it.

array.h:

```
extern const int N;
extern double array[];
```

arrayfill.h:

```
void arrayfill();
```

arraysum.h:

```
double sum(int var);
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "arrayfill.h"
#include "arraysum.h"

int main()
{
   arrayfill();
   double s = sum(10);
   return 0;
}
```

array.cpp:

```
#include "array.h"

const int N = 200;
double array[N];
```

arrayfill.cpp:

```
#include "array.h"
#include "arrayfill.h"

void arrayfill()
{
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }
}
```

arraysum.cpp:

```
#include "array.h"
#include "arraysum.h"

double sum(int var)
{
   double s = 0.0;
   for(int i=0;i<var;i++)
   {
      s+=array[i];
   }
   return s;
}
```

Build the program using g++:

```
g++ -c array.cpp
g++ -c arrayfill.cpp
g++ -c arraysum.cpp
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o arraytest array.o arrayfill.o arraysum.o main.o
```

Comment: I have tried this. But an error is coming : use of undeclared identifier 'sum'. For building the program i used : g++ array.cpp arrayfill.cpp arraysum.cpp main.cpp. And also I declared the array in arrayfill.cpp instead of a different header.

Comment: @ruskin23, I needed to add `#include "array.h"` to array.cpp. I didn't see the error about `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to declare the array in the header and have a `.cpp` file, where you define it:

`whatever.h`:

```
extern const size_t N = 42;
extern int array[N];
```

`whatever.cpp`:

```
include "whatever.h"

int array[N];
```

When the compiler just reads the include file, it will just note, that there is an array somewhere of size N. Only when you compile `whatever.cpp` the compiler will actually generate `array` in the data section. So then there is exactly one array in your linked application, though you reference it from many different places.

Comment: I recommend advising people to refrain from placing variables in headers.  Pass variables rather than using `extern`.

Comment: It can't be both `extern` and `static`.  It's either one or the other.

Comment: @legalize True. I took that from a static variable in a class. There this construction is OK. I have changed my answer accordingly

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sometimes you just need global variables, like e.g. `std::cout`. I agree, that you should have very good reasons for that.In my answer, I have not assessed the reasons to use global variables.

Answer (score 0):

In your header you wrote that you declared the array:

```
// header.h
int N;
double array[N];
```

Neither of these is a declaration.  Both of them are definitions.  To declare variables in a header you use the `extern` keyword:

```
// header.h
extern int N;
extern double array[N];
```

Furthermore, `N` can't be used as the size of an array unless it is a constant, so we need to declare `N` both `extern` and `const`:

```
// header.h
extern int const N;
extern double array[N];
```

In exactly one source file, the storage for `N` and `array` must be defined:

```
// source.cpp
int const N = 10;
double array[N];
```

In your header, you add declarations for the functions you intend to use:

```
// header.h
// ...as before
void arrayfill();
double sum(int var);
```

These are function declarations, not definitions.  In exactly one source file you would put their definitions as you've written them.